# Let $G$ be a group with $|G| = 5\cdot 7^2 \cdot 17$. Determine the possible structures for $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $|G| = 5\cdot 7^2 \cdot 17$. Determine the possible structures for $G$.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Sylow theorems might help. You can show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of each of order $5$ and $7$, and it has either $1$ or $35$ subgroups of order $17$. These two cases might lead to two different group structures.

Comment: Do you know how to work with semi-direct products?

Comment: i Know what they are but I cannot see how to apply them to this problem.

Comment: By Burnside's transfer theorem, $G$ is $p$-nilpotent for all primes $p$. Hence, $G$ is nilpotent, in fact abelian. Thus, $G$ is cyclic or $G\cong C_{595}\times C_7$.